# Permission Denied to write /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/events/kmem/kmalloc/trigger

Tags: linux, debugging, linux-kernel, sudo, trace

I am trying to run the following command on my `Ubuntu` machine

```
root@manav-R761-c:/# ls -la  /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/events/kmem/kmalloc/trigger
ls: cannot access /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/events/kmem/kmalloc/trigger: No such file or directory
root@manav-R761-c:/#
root@manav-R761-c:/# echo 'hash:stacktrace:bytes_req,bytes_alloc' > /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/events/kmem/kmalloc/trigger
bash: /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/events/kmem/kmalloc/trigger: Permission denied
```

I am logged in as `root`, then why I am not able to create trigger file and write to it?

Comment: Yes, I am able to read other files like `/sys/kernel/debug/usb/devices` but not able to create a new file in `/sys`

Comment: `mount | grep debug` command returned `none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)`

Comment: I have CONFIG_FUNCTIONAL_TRACER=y an addition to the default i386_defconfig and I have the file there.

Comment: I too have the trigger file on my rhel machine based off 3.16 kernel

Comment: @AndyShevchenko I too have `CONFIG_FUNCTION_TRACER=y` in my system but the `trigger` file is not there in `/sys`